# proof of the right continuity of a CDF (i.e. the Stieltjes measure function)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on the real line $\mathbb R$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  Define $F(t)\triangleq \mu((-\infty, t])$, i.e. the CDF (or the Stieltjes measure function).  I want to show that $F$ is right-continuous, but I'm not sure if my arguments (shown below) are correct.  I'd greatly appreciate it if someone can confirm it or correct me.

To show that $F(t)=\lim_{s\to t^+}F(s)$, it suffices to prove that $\lim_{s\to t^+}\mu((t,s])=0.$  To do so, I consider a sequence of open intervals $I_n=(t,t+2^{-n}), n=1,2,3,...$.  Since $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n=\emptyset$, we have $0=\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(I_n),$ where the last equality is due to the fact that $I_1\supset I_2\supset ....$  The claim then follows from the monotonicity of $\mu$ and the fact that for every $I_n$, we have $(t,s]\subset I_n$ for every $s \in I_n$.

Are these arguments correct?  The result holds for any nonnegative, countably additive measure on $\mathbb R$, doesn't it?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you already know that the measures of a decreasing sequence of sets decreases to their intersection (needs finiteness of the measure), you can directly use the result on the sets $(-\infty,t_n]$ where the sequence $(t_n)$ is decreasing with limit $t$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Indeed. Thanks a lot for pointing this out! It simplifies the proof. Also, $\mu$ needs to be finite for my arguments to hold too. (which of course is true for a probability measure.)